# Guess the next number formula

Tags: functions, summation, polynomials, products

I have a sequence of numbers such as {1,2,4,8,16}

The goal is to create a polynomial f(x) such that:

f(0)=1, f(1)=2, f(2)=4, f(n)=nth item on the list

I found this function which claims to do exactly that

But I cant seem to get it coded right on Mathematica.

[image]

Which for my sequence should give

[image]

and f(5)=31

Comment: These polynomials are called [Lagrange polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial)? For your example:

```
Expand @ InterpolatingPolynomial[
    {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 8}, {4, 16}},
    x
]
```

> 1 + (7 x)/12 + (11 x^2)/24 - x^3/12 + x^4/24